# How can i "Clean" output from sqlplus query?

Tags: oracle, batch-file, cmd, sqlplus

i have got simple query and i need just one value from it = VALID

The query is:

> select 'VALUE('||status||')' as value from user_indexes where index_name = '&1';

But i hve got in out:

```
C:\Program Files\zabbix\bin\win64\oracle>sqlplus -s @"C:\Program Files\zabbix\bi
n\win64\oracle\conn2.sql" OLAPTABLEVELSID
old   1: select status from user_indexes where index_name = '&1'
new   1: select status from user_indexes where index_name = 'OLAPTABLEVELSID'
VALID
```

What are this OLD and NEW strings? How can i dismiss it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET VERIFY OFF` should help you. Please add such line in your script before query.

Answer (score 1):

in sqplus you have substition variables. they are referenced by & or &&

when you run your script and pass it 'OLAPTABLEVELSID' - the query takes the '&1' and replaces it with ''OLAPTABLEVELSID'

SQL*Plus is telling you that in the output

```
SQL> set verify off
SQL> select '&1' from dual;
Enter value for 1: hello stackoverflow

'HELLOSTACKOVERFLOW
-------------------
hello stackoverflow
SQL>
```